# How to make react-router-dom return number instead of string in matched parameters

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router-dom

I'm using parameters in my routes with react-router-dom and doing a regex check to make sure the parameters match the expected type. For example:

`<Route path="/app/object/:objectId(\\d+)/" component={...} />`

This makes sure that the `objectId` is always a number in the url.

When I try to use this in redux via `mapStateToProps`, however, the `objectId` is of type `String` and needs to be explicitly cast to a Number for my filter to work.

Pseudo code:

```
const mapStateToProps (state, ownProps) => {
    return {
        obj: state.get('objects').find(object => object.get('id') === Number(ownProps.match.params.objectId)
    }
}
```

If I don't use a Number cast then I get a null result. But shouldn't the params be an `int` since I specified that in the path regex? Is there any way to force the parameters into the proper type?

Comment: Whats this `(\\d+)`?

Comment: No, a regex works on a *string*. So  a regex looking for numbers isn't looking for the number _type_, it's looking for numbers characters within a string. So the parameter itself will still be a string, cos the URL is a string. There's no reason matching numbers in a string in a URL would magically convert it to a `Number` type

Comment: Thanks @Jayce444, that makes sense. Know of any ways to cast the params after matching?

Comment: @shadyhill There's no configuration or anything like that I know of that will implicitly cast parameters. You'll just have to do it like you are now.